# Como obter o retorno de uma variavel em javascript com Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart

Colegas, por favor, preciso receber a variável de retorno desta biblioteca de criptografia abaixo.
Minha aplicação é em Flutter Web, e eu não sei como incluir JavaScript no Flutter Web.
Pesquisei bastante, mas realmente, não tenho resultado

**A Biblioteca de Criptografia:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://sandbox.boletobancario.com/boletofacil/wro/direct-checkout.min.js"></script>
```

**Obtendo o hash:**

Nesta etapa você precisará informar os dados do cartão para a nossa biblioteca, que irá validar dados do cartão, criptografá-los e retornar um hash.

Detalhamos a seguir um exemplo de utilização de nossa biblioteca de como obter o hash do cartão de crédito:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var checkout = new DirectCheckout('PUBLIC_TOKEN', false); 
  function generateHash() {
    var cardData = {
        cardNumber: '1111 2222 3333 4444',
        holderName: 'Nome do Titular',
        securityCode: '123',
        expirationMonth: '12',
        expirationYear: '2025'
      };
  }
  checkout.getCardHash(cardData, function(cardHash) {
      /* Sucesso - A variável cardHash conterá o hash do cartão */
  }, function(error) {
      /* Erro - A variável error conterá o erro ocorrido ao obter o hash */
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Não sei se tem essa possibilidade, e se tiver não deve ser a melhor opção. Procure uma forma de acesso direto ao serviço, API (https://juno.com.br/api/).

Verifique também:
https://github.com/tamojuno/direct-checkout-flutter

Comment: rubStackOverflow, obrigada pela sua colaboração, mas pelo que vi na documentação da Juno, isso não tem API, e a SDK do direct-checkout-flutter não funciona com Flutter Web, só android e ios. Já pedi suporte na Juno, mas não tive retorno

Comment: Hum.. Não percebi que era Flutter Web